# on Leopard / xcode 3.2.5 cannot deploy on ios5

Tags: ios, xcode

Everything seems to be fine with my provisioning profile, however on my new iPhone 4s with the latest update of iOS it seems that I cannot use it for deployment of my apps, its saying at Software Version in Oraganizer: iOS5 but I have xcode 3.2 , I don't know if there is a chance to use the device with iOS4 on my mac leopard without having to upgrade to Lion.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Any particular reason not to use Xcode 4.2? Edit: Ah, Leopard, not Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can run the iOS 5 SDK on XCode 3 - you will need to upgrade to Snow Leopard, at the very least (you don't have to upgrade to Lion), and then download XCode 4.2

Comment: I have Snow Leopard 10.6.8 and i saw i cannot go further... i don't know why?

Comment: If you go to developer.apple.com and log in with your developer ID you'll be able to download XCode 4 for Snow Leopard.